# How to allow render to web console from Trello API ips?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Sorry for my English. I am backend junior (Ruby on Rails).

I am working with Trello API. Now I am creating webhooks.
When webhook was created, I see this line in console:

```
Cannot render console from 107.23.149.70! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
```

I know that I can add line like this to config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '10.0.2.2'
```

But trouble is that Trello API IP and IP mask is different each time when I am doing requests.

How I can solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you currently getting `107.23.149.70` ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder as I said, each time Trello IP is different. If I add this IP to webconsole.whitelisted_ips, then try to create webhook, I see the same issue, but with different IP.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Trello is acting like a HTTP client when it executes a webhook back to your service. Since your app is in developer-mode, it has the ability to render the rails console in the browser for you. You don't want this exposed externally, remove your whitelist IP and ignore.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer seems correct.  However if you want to silence the console messages you can do that with, [see documentation](https://github.com/rails/web-console#configweb_consolewhiny_requests)

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.web_console.whiny_requests = false
end
```